# Easy way to convert coordinate systems between three views?

Tags: iphone

It's quiet complicated. I have four UIViews.

viewA acts as root container. viewB and viewC are childs of viewA.
So viewA contains viewB and viewC.

viewD is a child of viewB.

I try to "draw" it for you:

```
viewA OWNS ((viewB OWNS viewD) && viewC)
```

I rotate the layer's transform.rotation.z of viewB. So viewB is rotated a little bit. ViewD is also rotated a little bit relative to viewB.

Also, I rotate viewC the same way with an other value. So both viewB and viewC are rotated differently relative to viewA. viewD is rotated a little bit relative to viewB.

I need to convert all these coordinate systems in such a way, that the rotation of viewC can be specified relative to viewD. Or in other words: In such a way, that when the transform.rotation.z of viewC is the same as from viewD, both views appear to be rotated the same way (visually on screen).

A few weeks ago I was reading in some paper that UIKit provides support for converting coordinate systems. Any idea if they're suitable to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want viewD's transform to be independent of viewB? If so, make viewD a subview of viewA (if it's a later sibling than viewB, it will appear on top of it).

Comment: That would be fine, but when I rotate viewB, viewD must be rotated exactly the same way with no delay. That's why viewD is a subview of viewB. I didn't mention that there are 5 "copies" of viewD with different rotations. But all of them must rotate together with viewB.

Comment: If rotating viewB will lead to rotating viewD, then it must also lead to rotating viewC, because you want viewC's rotation and viewD's rotation to be equal. Or am I misunderstanding?